# Are we need to join the Magento community?

Tags: magento2, magento-community

Anyone can tell me.

I am a beginner Magento developer So are we need to join the Magento community?

If yes, What are the benefits of Magento community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just **my personal perspective**, joining to any **online communities** is up to your own discretion, it is not mandatory nor a requirement. But it can be very beneficial to someone, like us, who is just starting to learn or to get into a **specific subject matter**.
>
> **Magento Community** in particular has offered lots of online benefits for aspiring Magento developers. One of which is the **co-developer technical support**. You can find a specific help to a specific issue you have or might have in your magento development.
> Of course as we will become part of this community we will be imparting reliable information as well that might be helpful to others. As **Magento Community** is basically powered by exchanging and sharing of useful contents and information.

Comment: How many charges to join the Magento community?

Comment: what do you mean by charges? @Masud Shaikh

Comment: Magento Community is open for all interested members

Comment: Which means Magento Community is free to anyone who wish to join. :)

Comment: Ok, Its free to anyone. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not more idea about magento1.

In magento2.x

```
->Enables you to reuse third-party libraries without bundling them with source code.



->Component-based architecture with robust dependency management.



->Manages dependencies to reduce extension conflicts and compatibility issues.



->Versioned dependencies.
```

Semantic versioning.
Supports the PHP Framework Interoperability standard.

Refrence from 
[Magento 2: what are the benefits of installing magento 2 using composer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121210/magento-2-what-are-the-benefits-of-installing-magento-2-using-composer)